# Ribbon not visible in edit form even if user has contribute permissions on the list

Tags: 2010, permissions, ribbon

I have a SharePoint 2010 sub site where a user has only read permission on this site. I have an Announcement list on which I stopped inheritance and gave Contribute permission to the same user.

The issue is that the ribbon is not visible for him in the Edit form and therefore it is not possible to attach a file. Note that it becomes visible only when I grant contribute on the whole site.

Is there a way to get the ribbon visible to that user without giving the contribute on the site?

Comment: can you check if user is having another permission in check permissions?

Comment: Hi, he has only contribute on the list. He has read, limited access on the site.

Comment: Btw, if I give full control on the list, it still does not allow to view the ribbon.